# AJAX PHP MYSQL value update not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have this script which updates a counter in a mysql database but it's not working at all and i can't see what wrong as i am new into php and ajax:

```
$(function () {
        $('.press_me').click(function(){

    var button_ID= $(this).parent('tr').attr($row['ID']);
    $.post('counter.php', {button_ID: button_ID}, function(result){

          $($row['Teme_nefacute']).html(result);
        });
request.done(function( msg ) {

                                    alert('Success');
                                    return;

                              });
                              request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                                    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                                });
});
});
```

and counter.php:

```
    <?php
// Connection to database
  $connection=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo 'NOT_OK';
    //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

// Increasing the current value with 1
 mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE table SET amount= (amount + 1) WHERE ID=' " . $_POST["button_ID"] ." ' ");

$get_count= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `ID`=' " . $_POST["button_ID"] . " ' ");
$count_data= mysqli_fetch_array($new_count_data);
echo($count_data["amount"]);

  mysqli_close($connection);

  ?>
```

can anyone help me make it work async?

Comment: Are you sure `$row['ID']` is a variable in JavaScript? If you have it defined in PHP, you need to `<?php echo $row['ID'];` ?>` within your client-side code.

Comment: `mysqli_query("SELECT` that's a problem and make sure that `table` isn't the real table name in `UPDATE table SET`

Comment: @Fred-ii- what should i change?

Comment: no, it's not the real name

Answer (score 1):

First of all, PHP is a backend technology which works in server and sends result to client (browser, curl, wget etc.) Javascript is a frontend technology which works in the client. So in that point of view

Your php code should be between of `<?php //code ?>` tags, and it would executed in backend then result would be printed in javascript code.

As a result your view should be a php file. But it should contain html,js and php mixed.

```
   <script>
    $(function () {
      $('.press_me').click(function() {

        var button_ID= $(this).parent('tr').attr("<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>");
        $.post('counter.php', {button_ID: button_ID}, function(result) {

          $("<?php echo $row['Teme_nefacute']; ?>").html(result);
        });
        request.done(function(msg) {

          alert('Success');
          return;

        });
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
          alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Your php code looks OK. When you try like this what is the result ?

**Updated :**

If your table name is table then please place it  between this characters `` like in `SELECT` query. table has a special meaning in SQL.

Comment: unfortunately nothing.. i'm not  getting the 'success' message so i believe something is wrong in this script..

Comment: If you are using chrome or firefox open developer console, and look there for any javascript issue. Check these https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console

Comment: now it works, but i seem to have problems in counter.php, since i get the succes message but the values dont change

Comment: Yeah but you didn't give the problem details, your web server should throw errors in the error.log check there or in browser > developer console > console > right click > check Log XmlHttpRequest and click your button again, you would see is your request going to counter.php or is a 404 if it is going to it click on it you can get the response of the request check request body for any errors php throws, and write the error here.